# What does "can" mean in "The best we can expect"?

Tags: meaning, modal-verbs

What does “can” mean here?

“The best we **can** expect from our allies is the supply of food and ammo.”

Does it mean the ability to expect something?

Is it implying that other things (e.g direct involvement in the war by ally forces) are so unrealistic that we don’t have the ability to expect them?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: If we say that something is the best that we can expect, that means that we should not expect more, because if we do, we will be disappointed.

Comment: Does it mean we don’t have the ability to expect something else? As far as I know, “can” means ability. @MichaelHarvey

Comment: You ***can't*** (reasonably) expect impossible things to happen. In the cited context, it's assumed that the speaker isn't an idiot, so he won't / can't expect an unrealistic outcome. Effectively, *The best we can expect **unless we've taken leave of our senses**, is that [blah blah*

Comment: For example, John: *"You can't say I'm a woman."* Jane: *"Of course I can. You're a woman."* John: *"You can't **honestly / reasonably** say I'm a woman."* Jane: *"That's true!"*

Comment: Yes I think you are right. Lack of reasonableness is one of the things that deprive someone of his ability to expect something. “That’s the worst thing I can imagine.” means that I don’t have the ability to think of anything worse because that would be too unreasonable or unrealistic.

Answer (score 0):

Question: "What does “can” mean here?

“The best we can expect from our allies is the supply of food and ammo.”

Does it mean the ability to expect something?"

Answer: No, because to expect something does not involve ability (usually). It is *have the possibility to expect* here.

*can* is ability OR possibility

For example:
I can swim with you today, if you like. [possibility]
I can swim well. [ability]

Comment: Yes—and ability is sometimes classified as a kind of possibility ([CGEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cambridge_Grammar_of_the_English_Language) p. 184). [Collins COBUILD](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/can) has more examples showing the range of meanings of "can".

Comment: @nschneid The point here though was about possibility vs. ability. I am not writing a thesis on grammar. Just answering one question. And I can't even see that page.